# Debugging celery WorkerLostError with exitcode zero (Django 1.5.5 + celery 3.1.8 + RabbitMQ 3.1.3 on Heroku)

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

My platform runs through a lot of tasks (several thousand per day). Some of the longer tasks them keep failing with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1167, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0.
```

According to Celery's Flower, which doesn't provide anything more than the posted traceback, the task was received ( 2014-12-22 22:46:46.196814 ) four minutes before it was started ( 2014-12-22 22:50:03.469647 ), and failed in just ten seconds (epoch 1419288613.34 or 2014-12-22 22:50:13 ).

This has been a recurring problem on my platform. It happens *mostly* with tasks which run scrapy 0.24.2 but it may also happen with other tasks.

Other durations of WorkerLostError (also with an exit code of zero) are three minutes, five minutes, or seven minutes.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this? All tasks run perfectly fine locally. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

My recommendation is to check all of the modules you are using and your code for 'raise BaseException'.  I ran into the issue with WorkerLostError exitcode 0.

After a lot of debugging and figuring out specifically where tasks were failing, I found that it was when BaseException was raised.  Instead of providing the error message, WorkerLostError occurred.

By changing to 'raise Exception', the actual error message was provided when something went wrong inside the task.  This might not be the same for your case, but it was what I found when dealing with the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I have also noticed the same error:

```
[...ERROR/MainProcess] Task ... raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1175, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0.
```

not only with a `BaseException`, but also a custom exception subclassed from `BaseException`. Changing the base class to `Exception` allowed the actual exception to be raised along with the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

for me it was `sys.exit(0)` inside the task